# PHP: Trouble with mysql statement.

Tags: php, mysql, class

I am having a public function doing query for mysql. Everything works great in my local computer but having trouble once it was uploaded to the godaddy server. Basically, the `$rows` is null when I called the method.

I am sure the database data are correct and the  query should return few records. I have spent hours trying to figure it out but have no luck. I was hoping you guys can help me out on this one. Thanks in advance.

Code

```
    class test{

     public function getEmployees($username,$password) {



         $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,
              "SELECT name, password
               FROM employee
               WHERE name='$username' && password='$password'
               ");     

          $this->throwExceptionOnError();

          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
          $this->throwExceptionOnError();

          $rows = array();


          while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
              $rows[] = $row;
              $row = new stdClass();
              mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,  $row->name, $row->password);
          }
          if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)==0){

              return false;
          }else{
              return $rows;
          }



          mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
          mysqli_close($this->connection);
   }

}

$test=new test();
$row=$test->getEmployees('bob','1111');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";

//it prints nothing on the page
```

Comment: remove this line  $row = new stdClass(); and try

Comment: Thanks guys, I just figured it out. I had to change mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)==0 to mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt). Not sure why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is code structure.
Try:

```
class test{

     public function getEmployees($username,$password) {



         $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,
              "SELECT name, password
               FROM employee
               WHERE name='$username' && password='$password'
               ");     

          $this->throwExceptionOnError();

          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
          $this->throwExceptionOnError();

          $rows = array();
          $row = new stdClass();
          mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,  $row->name, $row->password);

          while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
              $rows[] = $row;

          }

          mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
          mysqli_close($this->connection);
          $temp = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt); 
          if($temp==0){

              return false;
          }else{
              return $rows;
          }



   }

}

$test=new test();
$row=$test->getEmployees('bob','1111');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks man. Please see my comment. Your code would work for me too. I will give u green. :D